# Querying using XQuery

Tags: xquery

XML data is stored in this format in sql server

```
   <Fields>
     <Field id="1" name="aa" value="00"/>
     <Field id="2" name="bb" value="11"/>
     <Field id="3" name="cc" value="22"/>
     <Field id="4" name="dd" value="33"/>
  </Fields>
```

I want to return all rows that meet a condition but return each xml in different format as:

```
   <Fields aa="00" bb="11" cc="22" dd="33">
   </Fields>
```

In other words,I want each of the field tag in the stored format to be returned  as an attribute  in the returned xml.

Expected format is  `<Fields aa="00" bb="11" cc="22" dd="33"> </Fields>`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a query that will accomplish your goals.  I assume you know how to retrieve the XML data from your server; here I address it inline with the variable `$fields`:

```
xquery version "1.0";

let $fields :=
    <Fields>
        <Field id="1" name="aa" value="00"/>
        <Field id="2" name="bb" value="11"/>
        <Field id="3" name="cc" value="22"/>
        <Field id="4" name="dd" value="33"/>
    </Fields>
return
    <Fields>{
        for $field in $fields/Field
        let $name := $field/@name
        let $value := $field/@value
        return 
            attribute { $name } { $value }
    }</Fields>
```